# Is the real world address of Rose Tyler's flat known?

Tags: doctor-who, real-location

I'm currently in London and as far as sight-seeing goes for a Doctor Who fan ... well, let's just say a picture of Bad Wolf's flat would be the whovianst thing to send back to my fellow Whovians back at home.

Is the address known? Can somebody extrapolate this? I think there was an episode where you could see some well known buildings out of the apartment's window, but I don't remember which.

I mean we see a lot of spots around her place, there should be something recognisable, right?

---

Edit: Clarification, just to make sure. I'm **NOT** talking about the place where Billie Piper lives, but the address of the Rose Tyler's home.

Answer (score 13):

Although the show constantly refers to Rose and family as living in London, the reality is that almost all of the scenes involving Rose's flat (and the Powell Estate in general) were filmed on location in **Cardiff** according to [this website](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/stories/rose) about the filming of Dr Who.

The closest you're going to get **in London** is the corner of the "[Brandon Estate](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/locations/brandonestate)" shown in the "Christmas Invasion" episode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the one I meant. Thanks. It's great to have a regular answer machine on the site. Great Job!

Comment: @bitmask - I expect you to post pictures of any sites visited.

Comment: Sure will do :)

Comment: @bitmask -  I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Lydstep Flats"
The middle building as they lived in  #48.

48 Lydstep Flats, Lydstep Crescent, Cardiff CF14 2QU, UK

GOOGLE MAPS LINK
https://www.google.com/maps/place/43+-+84+Lydstep+Flats,+Cardiff+CF14+2QW,+UK/@51.4997641,-3.2138552,201m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x486e1b6ef278e413:0x89aef9b135d395f3!2sLydstep+Flats,+Lydstep+Cres,+Cardiff+CF14+2QX,+UK!3b1!8m2!3d51.4993329!4d-3.2133122!3m4!1s0x486e1b6ef9eb05df:0x317d4cb31328ae52!8m2!3d51.4997585!4d-3.2127752?hl=en

Comment: Could you possible provide a source for you info?

Comment: You can find some supporting info [here](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/locations/lydstepflats).